# ¿Como implementar un sistema IIR en Matlab?

Tags: controller, matlab, vectores

requiero implementar un sistema IIR (infinite impulse response) en Matlab usando la forma matemática estándar que se muestra a continuación en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intentando hacerlo con el siguiente codigo pero no he obtenido el resultado deseado, necesito ayuda urgente, llevo varios días pensando el ejercicio.

```
B = [0.48 -1.43 1.43 -0.48];
x = [1; zeros(19,1)]';

M = length(B);
N = length(A);
nx = length(x);    %longitud de la señal de salida
long = nx+M-1;

y = zeros(1,M);
r = zeros(1,M);
Y =zeros(nx,long);
R = zeros(nx,long);

for i = 1:nx
    if i>1
        for j = 1:N
            r(i,j) = A(j).*Y(i,j);
        end
    end
    R(i,i:i-1+M) = r(i,:);

    for k = 1:M
        y(i,k) = B(k)*x(i);
    end
    Y(i+1,i:i-1+M) = y(i,:)-r(i,:);     
end

% sumando:
for  L = 1:long
    S(L) = sum(Y(:,L));   
end
```